# DB table update using Groovy SQL's withBatch

Tags: sql, groovy

My code is as:

```
String updateQuery = "Update "+table+" Set "+columnToModify+"=:newvalue Where "+keyColumn+"=:keyvalue";
int[] modifyCount = sql.withBatch(batchSize, updateQuery) { ps ->
    keyValue.each { k,v ->
        ps.addBatch(keyvalue:k, newvalue:v)
    }
}
```

`batchSize` is 100, while `keyValue` size is 221.

So I expect that three batches are fired with size 100,100,21. And modifyCount has three entries of 100,100,21.

But modifyCount has instead 221 entries of value 1 each.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is not about the batch size, but about the queries executed.  So given, that your DB contains a single line for each `keyvalue`, you get the *221* for each queries executed (the batch size is no concern here) and the *1* for updates executed by each.

[From the docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#withBatch(int,java.lang.String,groovy.lang.Closure)):

> **Returns:**
>
> an array of update counts containing **one element for each binding in the batch**. The elements of the array are ordered according to the order in which commands were executed.

Comment: So how do I do this update in batches of ,say 100, to get performance improvement. This is test program. In production env, number of records I need to update may be around 100000.

Comment: What makes you think you did not?  The batching is done inside the withBatch function for you.

Comment: I was confused a bit as you said that batchsize is not a concern here.